# Using in operator with Pandas series

Tags: pandas

Why can't I match a string in a Pandas series using `in`? In the following example, the first evaluation results in False unexpectedly, but the second one works.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': [ 'Adam', 'Ben', 'Chris' ]})
'Adam' in df['name']
'Adam' in list(df['name'])
```

Comment: `df['name'].eq('Adam').any()`

Comment: This is where a [mcve] comes in handy.  As it is, your question fails to specify if you want `'Adam' <some operation> 'Adams'` to be `True`.  Do you want a series of `True`/`False` signifying the truth for each element?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### In the first case:

Because the `in` operator is interpreted as a call to `df['name'].__contains__('Adam')`. If you look at the implementation of `__contains__` in `pandas.Series`, you will find that it's the following (inhereted from `pandas.core.generic.NDFrame`) :

```
def __contains__(self, key):
    """True if the key is in the info axis"""
    return key in self._info_axis
```

so, your first use of `in` is interpreted as:

```
'Adam' in df['name']._info_axis
```

This gives `False`, expectedly, because `df['name']._info_axis` actually contains information about the `range/index` and not the data itself:

```
In [37]: df['name']._info_axis 
Out[37]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)

In [38]: list(df['name']._info_axis) 
Out[38]: [0, 1, 2]
```

---

#### In the second case:

```
'Adam' in list(df['name'])
```

The use of `list`, converts the `pandas.Series` to a list of the values. So, the actual operation is this:

```
In [42]: list(df['name'])
Out[42]: ['Adam', 'Ben', 'Chris']

In [43]: 'Adam' in ['Adam', 'Ben', 'Chris']
Out[43]: True
```

---

Here are few more idiomatic ways to do what you want (with the associated speed):

```
In [56]: df.name.str.contains('Adam').any()
Out[56]: True

In [57]: timeit df.name.str.contains('Adam').any()
The slowest run took 6.25 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 144 µs per loop

In [58]: df.name.isin(['Adam']).any()
Out[58]: True

In [59]: timeit df.name.isin(['Adam']).any()
The slowest run took 5.13 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 191 µs per loop

In [60]: df.name.eq('Adam').any()
Out[60]: True

In [61]: timeit df.name.eq('Adam').any()
10000 loops, best of 3: 178 µs per loop
```

Note: the last way is also suggested by @Wen in the comment above

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Is there a more idiomatic way to do #2?

Comment: Given that `list(series)` produces a list of its values, and `iter(series)` produces an iterator over its values, how could anyone possibly expect that `series.__contains__` checks the *index* instead of the values? Seems like a major flaw in the Series API. (But thank you for this explanation, I was pulling my hair out for a while before finding this answer).

Comment: This answer is completely wrong.  (At least when using Pandas version 0.25.3.)  It's understandable and efficient to simply use `'Adam' in df['name'].values`.

Comment: @Mr.LanceESloan It can be supplemented by the fact that, if you are not afraid of confusing `DataFrame` values, it is indeed quicker to check `DataFrame` values directly than column ones because attribute access takes a comparable long time

Answer (score -1):

```
found = df[df['Column'].str.contains('Text_to_search')]
print(len(found))
```

`len(found)` will give you the number of number of matches in column.