# How to loop through a column in a dataframe to search for a specific value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset of pet names and owners:

```
Pets    Owners
dog     James
dog     Katelyn
rat     Shelly
cat     Bob
```

I want to be able to search through the Owners column to find the name Katelyn and then print out a vector names for the given owner. So far I have this:

```
def pet_name():
    owner = input("What is the Owner name? ")

    # check to see if owner exist in pets dataset
    # if ownderID exist then print corresponding pet names
    if owner in pets['Owners']: 
        print( pets[['Pets','Owners']][pets.Owners == owner])

    # if ownerID doesnt' exist
    elif not age: 
        print("Sorry, this Owner doesn't exist. Try again! ")


    # if no ownerID has been entered at all 
    else: 
        print("You didn't enter any Owner. Try again! ")
```

When I enter a name to search, it automatically goes to the else portion of the code. How can I fix this? Should I use itterows()?

Comment: Don't use iterrows. Simple use `loc`.. `pets.loc[pets.Owners == 'Katelyn', 'Pets']`

Comment: For which part of the code? loc.. allows me to select certain part of the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking if `owner in pets['Owners']` you are using `pets` in a dictionary context and it checks if `owner` is in the index of `pets`.  Instead check if `owner in pets['Owners'].values`

That said, I'd rather see `pet_name` written like this:

```
def pet_name():
    owner = input("What is the Owner name? ")

    # check to see if owner exist in pets dataset
    # if ownderID exist then print corresponding pet names
    mask = pets['Owners'] == owner
    if mask.any():
        print(pets.loc[mask, ['Pets', 'Owners']])

    # if ownerID doesnt' exist
    elif not age: 
        print("Sorry, this Owner doesn't exist. Try again! ")


    # if no ownerID has been entered at all 
    else: 
        print("You didn't enter any Owner. Try again! ")
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! However, I would need it in a vector format ( list/array). So, how can I put it that way? Use list()?

Comment: I don't know what you mean "I would need it".  What is "it"?

Comment: What operation does 'mask' and 'any()' perform?

Comment: You should play around with it and see.  `mask` is a variable name I set equal to `pets['Owners'] == owner`.  It is a `pandas.Series` of boolean dtype.  The `any` method of a boolean series returns `True` if any of the values are `True`.  I did it this way because I only have to evaluate all the members of the series equal to `owner` one time and then use it in both the evaluation of the `if` statement and in the call to `loc` in order to slice the dataframe.

Comment: How can get the result to be put in a vector format? as a list? Should I use list()?

Comment: what is the "result"?  You haven't made that clear. `pets.loc[mask, ['Pets', 'Owners']]`?  And, what do you mean by "vector format"?  I might possibly be able to guess at what you mean but it would be easier if you told me what it is you are trying to return.  At the moment, your function doesn't return anything.  It only prints stuff.

Comment: So the result will display the corresponding Pet type along with the Owner.                                     Pets      Owner                                                    dog        Katelyn                                                   I would like to some how put this in a vector format. Vector format such as an array. I don't want it to return anything, I just want it to print.

Comment: So instead of `print(...)` do `return ...`

Comment: It's [recommended](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html#pandas-series-values) to use `pandas.Series.array` instead of `pandas.Series.values`. Also, could you check out my answer to see if it has any inconsistencies?  Thank you.

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani and for others.  As of Pandas version 0.24 the property `array` is available for a Pandas Series object and will return a Pandas array.  It will now work for versions prior to that.  So for versions >= 0.24 `owner in pets['Owner'].array` will work.  As for why it is recommended, I'll have to explore that in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's see what the problem is, then we can find a way to fix it.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: pets = pd.read_csv('pets.csv')

In [3]: pets
Out[3]:
  Pets   Owners
0  dog    James
1  dog  Katelyn
2  rat   Shelly
3  cat      Bob

In [4]: type(pets["Owners"])
Out[4]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

We can see that `pets` is a [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) object. Now the problem is obviously in this line of code:

```
if owner in pets['Owners']:
```

Here's why [you can't use `in` operator with `pandas.Series`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49393472/6282576), but basically, it's because the developers of `Pandas` didn't implement this module in a way that would be possible to use "[Membership test operations](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations)" like this. Therefore, as you mentioned yourself, this will always return `False`:

```
In [5]: owner in pets["Owners"]
Out[5]: False
```

Now, if you want to use `pets["Owners"]` you can do it like this (as suggested by [@piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56120293/6282576)):

```
In [6]: owner in pets["Owners"].values
Out[6]: True
```

However, if we look at the documentation for [`pandas.Series.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html#pandas-series-values):

> **Warning:** We recommend using [Series.array](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.array.html#pandas.Series.array) or [Series.to_numpy()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html#pandas.Series.to_numpy),
>   depending on whether you need a reference to the underlying data or a
>   NumPy array.

So we can do it like this:

```
In [7]: owner in pets["Owners"].array
Out[7]: True
```

There's also a better way of doing it, you want to find out if "there are any pets for a given owner," correct? If so, you can do it like this:

```
In [8]: pet = pets.loc[pets["Owners"] == owner, "Pets"]

In [8]: if pet.any():
   ...:     print(pet)
   ...: else:
   ...:     print("You didn't enter any Owner. Try again! ")
Out[8]:
1    dog
Name: Pets, dtype: object
```

As you can see, this will print a `pandas.Series` object. You have [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56120244/how-to-loop-through-a-column-in-a-dataframe-to-search-for-a-specific-value#comment98873893_56120293) that you need it in a "vector/list/array" format. It's a bit unclear, but I think the situation is that an `owner` can have multiple `pets` and you want to check if the `owner` has any `pets`, and then print *all* of their `pets` in a list-type format. If so, you can use `pet.array`. For example, if we modify your dataset so that *Katelyn* has more than one pet:

```
Pets    Owners
dog     James
dog     Katelyn
rat     Katelyn <-----
rat     Shelly
cat     Bob
```

Then we can see that it gives us a list:

```
In [9]: if pet.any():
    ...:     print(pet.array)
    ...: else:
    ...:     print("You didn't enter any Owner. Try again! ")
Out[9]: 
<PandasArray>
['dog', 'rat']
Length: 2, dtype: object
```