# How to solve pandas dataframe column is not recognizing its value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using Kaggle [Spotify 1921-2020](https://www.kaggle.com/yamaerenay/spotify-dataset-19212020-160k-tracks) (data.csv) dataset which contain a column 'artists' which is of `object` datatype, I tried to perform conditional extraction on the data-frame `spotify[spotify['artists'] == 'Dennis Day']` it outputs no row it happens no matter what value I put in. I tried to change its data type to `str` `spotify.artists.apply(str)` but still, nothing happened and its datatype is still showing as `object`

What I did till now

```py
# previously the value was like
0                                       ['Dennis Day']
1    ['Sergei Rachmaninoff', 'James Levine', 'Berli...


# I remove the square braces
spotify['artists'] = spotify['artists'].apply(lambda x : x[1:-1])

0                                         'Dennis Day'
1    'Sergei Rachmaninoff', 'James Levine', 'Berlin...

# since it was giving no output for any value I checked this
for i in songs.artists.head(10):
    print(f'{i} is present {i in songs.artists}')

# and see what I get

'Dennis Day' is present False
'Sergei Rachmaninoff', 'James Levine', 'Berliner Philharmoniker' is present False
'John McCormack' is present False

# don't get confused if somewhere it is written songs and instead of spotify they are same.
```

I tried to change Kaggle notebook to jupyterlab but it's same all around so what should I do now

Comment: How about `"'Dennis Day'"`?

Comment: It seems to me that the single ticks are included in the string.

Comment: still the same result @Kris

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393053/using-in-operator-with-pandas-series

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using in operator with Pandas series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393053/using-in-operator-with-pandas-series)

Comment: Yeah it helped me to understand why it's giving me an error but I am still not able to do conditional extraction on that dataframe @Kris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the conditional extraction on the data-frame, try using `.loc`:

```
spotify.loc[spotify['artists'] == 'Dennis Day']
```