# Why does "in" work for a pandas Series in a list comphrension and not as a logical expression

Tags: python, pandas, logic, list-comprehension, series

If I want to loop through values in a Series, I can do that using the `in` operator

```
[x for x in pd.Series(['Hello, World!'])]

> ['Hello, World!']
```

but if I use `in` to check if `Hello, World!` is in the Series, it returns `False`.

```
'Hello, World!' in pd.Series(['Hello, World!'])

> False
```

Paradoxically (to the untrained eye), this behavior makes the following list comprehension return empty:

```
hello_series = pd.Series(['Hello, World!'])

[x for x in hello_series if x in hello_series]

> []
```

This is Series-specific behavior; it of course works fine with lists:

```
'Hello, World!' in ['Hello, World!']

> True
```

Why does `in` work in one context and not the other with Series, and for what reason(s)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine whether a Pandas Column contains a particular value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319929/how-to-determine-whether-a-pandas-column-contains-a-particular-value)

Comment: `print('Hello, World!' in pd.Series(['Hello, World!']).values)`

Comment: Here is a pretty good answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393053/using-in-operator-with-pandas-series/49393472

Comment: @jch Thanks, this is right on the practical side of the question.

Comment: @KristianCanler, actually the very first line of the accepted answer address the **why** question - because **in of a Series checks whether the value is in the index:**.

Comment: Why does it do that is the question I'm asking. I'm looking to understand the behavior at a design level rather than just a literal level. If there's something in SO guidelines about not asking design questions I can just edit that out and close my question as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if you're asking a practical question or a theoretical one.  The theoretical answer is that whoever wrote the Panda code made a specific design decision.

- Python interprets `x in thing` by calling `y.__contains__(x)`.
- Python interprets `for x in thing:` by creating an iterator for `thing` and then getting items from that iterator until the iterator throws an exception indicating it has run out of items.  A `thing` can either implement `__iter__` to be explicit about its iterator, or Python can sometimes infer one (the `thing` has both a `len(thing)` and `thing[i]`).

The fact that both of these constructs has `in` in syntax obviously indicates that they're related.  But their implementations for a specific object can have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: The second bullet doesn't quite spell out why `__iter__` doesn't work on the Series, but the answer @jch posted spells that out. So then the "theoretical" question ["for what reasons"] would be why pandas was designed so that pd.Series._info_axis contains information about range/index and not the data itself

Comment: The second theoretical question is why  Python is set up where one (operator?) (`in`) is used to call two different (methods?) instead of having two different operators. That's Python behavior, right, not something specific to pandas?