# Check if elements list are in column DataFrame

Tags: python, list, dataframe, loops

**Objective**: I have a **list** of 200 elements(urls) and I would like to check if each one is in a specific column of the **Dataframe**. If it is, I would like to remove the element from the list.

**Problem**: I am trying a similar solution by adding to a new **list** the ones that are not there but it adds all of them.

```
pruned = []
for element in list1:
    if element not in transfer_history['Link']:
        pruned.append(element)
```

I have also tried the solution I asked for without success. I think it's a simple thing but I can't find the key.

```
for element in list1:
    if element in transfer_history['Link']:
        list1.remove(element)
```

Comment: Can you make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this? Aka, can you include a smaller list and simpler DataFrame for testing~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, your syntax for `transfer_history['Link']` is the entire column itself. You need to call each item in the column using another array `transfer_history['Link'][x]`. Use a for loop to iterate through each item in the column.

Or a much easier way is to just check if the item is in a list made of the entire column with a one liner:

```
pruned = []
for element in list1:
    if element not in [link for link in transfer_history['Link']]:
        pruned.append(element)
```

Comment: It worked the first option. Thanks so much!!!!!

Comment: No problem! I've updated my answer for you. Hope this makes it clearer to understand.

Comment: "You're essentially checking if one url is equal to the entire column." - this isn't the problem. Also, don't use the 2nd option which removes elements from `list1` while iterating over it. It will often have unexpected results.

Comment: @Stuart. You are right. What I meant was that he needs to check if the element is in each cell of the data frame, rather than the entire cells / column itself. Edited and removed.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `in` with a pandas series, [you are searching the index, not the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393053/using-in-operator-with-pandas-series). To get around this, convert the column to a list using `transfer_history['Link'].tolist()`, or better, convert it to a set.

```
links = set(transfer_history["Link"])
```

A good way to filter the list is like this:

```
pruned = [element for element in list1 if element not in links]
```

[Don't remove elements from the list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating), which may have unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the urls doesn't matter, this can be simplified a lot using sets:

```
list1 = list(set(list1) - set(transfer_history['Link']))
```